# Multiply a measure by a single value

Tags: parameters, powerbi, dax, measure

I'm very new to Power BI and DAX. I've created a measure that currently looks like this:

```
Testing123 = [TotalSales] + CelebrationQuery[CelebrationSalesPercentage] * 10538473
```

I don't want that hard-coded value in there. In order to generate that value, this is the calcuation:

```
CALCULATE([TotalSales], FILTER(CelebrationQuery[value] = "")
```

When I replace the hard-coded value with this calculation, it doesn't end up in the table I created. Everything is blank, except for the instance where the celebration type is blank.

The table consists of only 4 things: Celebration type, Sales %, Sales Volume, and the measure that I'm trying to get to work...Projected Sales Volume.

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question to ask, but I've been stuck for quite some time now.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that your calculation is being evaluated in the filter context of the table you have it in. You need to remove or replace that filter context.

Try this instead:

```
CALCULATE([TotalSales], CelebrationQuery[value] = "")
```

Here the `CALCULATE` *replaces* the filter context with the specified one rather than *adding* that filter to the calculation environment.

This should be the same as the following:

```
CALCULATE([TotalSales], FILTER(ALL(CelebrationQuery[value]), CelebrationQuery[value] = ""))
```

Comment: Hi Alexis, thank you for getting back to me! Your edit worked, but it only works when I include the [blank] celebration type on my table. Once I filter out the [blank] celebration, it re-calculates Projected Sales Volume to be the same as the Current Sales Volume.

Comment: Try `ALLSELECTED(CelebrationQuery)` rather than `ALL(CelebrationQuery[value])`. The latter only removes filters on that single column, but it sounds like you've got other columns involved.

Comment: Still coming up with the same result!  What about parameters...is there anyway to store a parameter based off of this criteria? I can't seem to find a way to input a calculation and store it as a parameter.

Comment: Sort of. A measure with a fixed filter context will act as a constant parameter. I just haven't figured out what you want that fixed filter context to be. Does using a simple `ALL(CelebrationQuery)` work for what you want? That removes all filter context including any filters you put on the table. I don't know what context you evaluated `10538473` in, but that's what you need to replicate using some version of `ALL` / `ALLEXCEPT` / `ALLSELECTED`.

Comment: Okay, I definitely made some headway. The following calculation gave me the $10M number on every single cell: 

CALCULATE([TotalSales], FILTER(ALL(CelebrationQuery[value]), CelebrationQuery[value] = ""))

The only filter that I have applied is a Date filter (at the page level).

When I go to the table and filter off the "" celebrations, the fixed $10M disappears from every cell. I created another column called [Captured] where 0 is "" and 1 is anything else. When I filter on that, the same result...the fixed $10M disappears from every cell.